# unicode in javascript problam with fromCharCode while adding value

Tags: javascript, unicode

fromCharCode function for language message conversion but its nt working only working when used like this

```
String.fromCharCode(2991, 3006, 2996, 3009, 2990, 2994, 2991, 2985, 3015)
```

but if put string or array then  not working at all please guide me

```
 var n1 = '2991,3006,2996,3009,2990,2994,2991,2985,3015';
 var numberArray = [2991,3006,2996,3009,2990,2994,2991,2985,3015];
 var n=String.fromCharCode(numberArray);
 alert(n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `String.fromCharCode` works on `arguments`, the right definition is the first you provided. If you need to use the other ones you have to use `apply`:

```
var arr = [2991,3006,2996,3009,2990,2994,2991,2985,3015],
    converted = String.fromCharCode(String, a);
```

Or, if you need to use a string, just do split it into an array and then `apply` the method above.

```
var str = '2991,3006,2996,3009,2990,2994,2991,2985,3015',
    arr = str.split(','),
    converted = String.fromCharCode(String, a);
```

A little and very basic function which covers all of them:

```
function convert() {
    var arr = [],
        arg = arguments[0];
    if(typeof arg === 'number') { // assume all args are numbers, split them into the array
        arr = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0);
    } else if(typeof arg === 'string') { // string, let's split it into an array!
        arr = arg.split(',');
    } else if(typeof arg === 'object') { //typeof returns object, but it should be an array
        arr = arguments[0];
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);
}
```

Use this like `convert('2991,3006,2996,3009,2990,2994,2991,2985,3015')` or `convert([2991,3006,2996,3009,2990,2994,2991,2985,3015])` and will return the same result.